# how can I ignore nested patterns with regex

Tags: regex

Not sure if the title is the best way to describe the problem, but what I need to achieve is the following :

I have a list of strings that follow a fairly simple pattern, so string values optionally followed by a note/remark, using brackets. Aim is to isolate the bracketed part, which works fine as long as there are no other brackets within the bracket part

For example :

```
This is some string (with comment)
```

Can be split as follows (very lazy)

```
regex.Pattern = "^(.*)(\(.*\))$"
```

and it provides me output as follows and as expected.

```
part 1 : This is some string
part 2 : (with comment)
```

The problem is that sometimes I can have strings as follows

```
This is some string (with comment (and even more comment))
```

And I'm failing to get the correct output. What I need to acchieve is the following :

```
part 1 : This is some string
part 2 : (with comment (and even more comment))
```

So how can I achieve this ?

Comment: What language/tool is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `.*` to do a [non-greedy match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)  by adding a reluctant quantifier `?` next to the `*`

```
^(.*?)(\(.*\))$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nH8eT5/7)

OR

```
^([^(]*)(\(.*\))$
```

Comment: Better will be: `^([^(]*)(\(.*\))`

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
^([^(]*)(\(.*\))$
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/gE9wO7/2)

Answer (score 1):

**Another simple solution:**

```
^(.*?)(\(.+)$
```

**Demo:**
http://regex101.com/r/vQ9xM4/1